# How to close webview in mobile android/iOs(Native app)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, native

In our app have opening one url in webview there is way to close webview after some specific url detect.
how can possible to close webview ? I have try with `window.close()` in javascript.but could not work.have another way from android or ios app.

Comment: You can simply set visibility of that webview.

Comment: Native or hybrid ? Which technology ?

Comment: Native android :: wbview.removeAllViews(); wbview.destroy();

Comment: In native app have an issue

Comment: By closing web view, do you mean navigating back from web view screen to the previous screen ?

Comment: yes .navigating back from web view screen to the previous screen

Comment: @BhaveshChauhan show me your native code.

Comment: You can set visibility of that webview as said by @UpendraShah

Comment: you can't close WebVIew, it is not something that can be closed. What do you mean by closing a WebView?

Comment: provide the code how you are doing this, which is creating issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*As per comments on question*, I am putting a better term for closing the web view - **going back to previous screen**. You can do this as follows for Android and iOS :

**Android :**

```
finish()
```

**iOS :**

If you are using navigation controller :

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you are presenting web view controller :

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The key is to check that url in the delegate function of web view.

**Android :**

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals("your_url")) {
            finish()
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**iOS :**

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.url?.absoluteString == "your_url" {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            // If controller is presented -  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)  
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldoverrideurlloading)

> Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current `WebView`. If `WebViewClient` is not provided, by default `WebView` will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url. If `WebViewClient` is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current `WebView` handles the url.

**Notes:**

- This method is not called for requests using the `POST` "method".
- This method is also called for subframes with non-http schemes, thus it is strongly disadvised to unconditionally call `loadUrl(String)` with the request's url from inside the method and then return true, as this will make `WebView` to attempt loading a non-http url, and thus fail.

**Here is the sample demo**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod?tab=topactivity");

    }


    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals("https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod?tab=profile")) {

                finish() ;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL DETECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // perform your action here
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: OP has already mentioned in the question comments that he wants to go to previous screen.

Comment: @Nitish thanks i have updated my **BTW** i have also added comment  to perform his reqired action as per requirement in my answer please check again

Comment: @nilesh here need to create custom webview?(as per my android developer say)

Comment: @BhaveshChauhan no need to create custom webview just create new custom `WebViewClient` same as in my answer it will work fine

Answer (score -2):

In iOS you would now be using Safari sfview so directly picking up a URL is blocked for security hence the only universal solution you can apply in both Android and iOS apps is deep linking.

You can trigger to close the safari sf view when you reach that specific URL using deep link.

Google deep link and follow the examples.

Answer (score -4):

Use this can help you

```
  myWebView.destroy();
  myWebView = null;
```